# PocketBeagle Debian Internet sharing via USB - what am I missing?

Tags: windows-10, network-protocols, beagleboard, debian-buster

I have a fresh pocketBeagle that I'm trying to update, by sharing my laptop's (windows 10) internet connection over USB.
I've been trying to follow these two guides (not much difference between them):

- https://manpages.debian.org/buster/traceroute/traceroute.1.en.html
- https://ofitselfso.com/BeagleNotes/HowToConnectPocketBeagleToTheInternetViaUSB.php

General idea seems to be pocketBeagle takes 192.168.7.2 and uses 192.168.7.1 as default gw
As far as I can tell, I've followed all the instructions but I cannot ping anything outside these two connections from the pocketBeagle.

What tests can I do to figure out where the connection is failing?

---

Current state:

ping 8.8.8.8 never returns from PuTTY,
standard windows defender firewall settings

[Debian system ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ZY0.png)
ip 192.168.7.2

[My internet connection with network sharing turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCPoi.png)
all enabled, selected PocketBeagle (Eth 4)

[Eth4's ipv4 config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97yjj.png)
ip 192.168.7.1

[Default Gateway in Debian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd845.png)
file exists

[/etc/resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adtWf.png)
nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: That "file exists" is very suspicious. What does `route -n` say on Debian? Please use text if possible, not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here's the output:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb1
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0

Comment: That looks correct, 192.168.7.1 is set as the default gateway. Try pinging that address first from your beagle (to see how far you can get), then your local gateway (i.e. the router your ISP gave you), then 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Tarmo, ultimately I think the problem was with some third-party program on my laptop, because I've just tried it on another computer and it's happy now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to connect using a different computer and everything is working fine.

I'm not sure who the culprit was, but my guess is Avast doing something defensive.